# On Edit trigger not running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have an installed trigger on my google sheets project that is supposed to fire every time there is an edit, but for some reason it is random in when it actually fires. At times it will only do it every couple of edits, at other times it will go dead for a few hours and I won't be able to get it to work, then spontaneously decide to work again. I've tested this by actually looking at the executions and indeed the trigger is only going off intermittently. Am I missing something about triggers here?

Comment: If there's any chance it's always firing but something in the code isn't executing due to an if statement or something etc, would you add your code to your question. :) Else, try deleting the trigger and reinstalling it. Let us know if this isn't it and we'll think of something else.

Comment: Try using the [logger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger) to determine if the trigger is firing by recording a variable value to the log.